# Reading all the column automatically

Tags: java

When I want to make a method to read a table and return the read data and I don't know how many columns there are (in case of writing a general method), I usually make another function that gets the number of columns and using a for loop I pass the result set values to single line string, separate them by a tab charterer and store them in a list.

My question is that, is there any built in method in java that can handle this, I mean when you do not know how many columns there are and you want to read the whole row at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **ResultSetMetaData** object to get number of column. There is getMetaData() method of **ResultSet** class. Then you can get all row via loop. But there is no built in method for whole row.

Comment: That was exactly what I meant, thank you Ugur I'll accept this answer.